# mysql error: code 1005 cant create table erno 150

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been looking around online, erno 150 seems to be a common problem, but i am struggling with this code, any help?

```
create table players
(
email varchar(30) not null,
playerpassword varchar(30),
screenName varchar (8),
primary key (email)
);

create table scores
(
screenName varchar(8),
gameword varchar(30),
score long,
foreign key (screenName) references players(screenName)
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

`screenName` needs to be a key on the players table to be used as a foreign key in another table.  You can just add `key (screenName)` to the table definition for `players`.  Maybe you even want it to be a `unique key`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be referencing the primary key, not an arbitrary column.  However, I would recommend that you use auto incremented primary keys.  Something like this:

```
create table players (
    playerId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    email varchar(30) not null,
    playerpassword varchar(30),
    screenName varchar(8),
    unique (email)
);

create table scores (
    scoreId int not null auto_increment primary key
    playerId int not null,
    gameword varchar(30),
    score long,
    foreign key (playerId) references players(playerId)
);
```

Comment: This answer is much better.  `screenName` could still be useful as a key, though.